# Change Value in VisualState

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I use ControlTemplate to create different styles for a button. It targets the type Button of course. I can change the colors of the button for different VisualStates, but they are all hard typed or they are reference to a static resource.

Example:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

At the page I placed a button:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ButtonDefaultStyle}" 
        Background="Yellow"
        Content="Hello" />
```

The button is yellow and when you pressed it, it will become blue.

Now the question, how can I change the color of the VisualState::Pressed? To me it's a cumbersome to create a ControlTemplate for each different color button.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express Update 3. This is for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 using the Universal SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up to create a custom control that inherits Button. In that class I created a bunch of dependency properties that allows me to set different colors for each state.

The resource dictionary looks like this for the button:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=PressedColor}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>            
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

The button on the page itself look like this:

```
<cc:ButtonStandard Style="{StaticResource ButtonStandardStyle}"
                   Content="Hello Visual Studio" 
                   Background="Red"
                   PointerOverColor="Blue"
                   PressedColor="Orange" 
                   DisabledColor="White"/>
```

PressedColor is a Dependency Property inside ButtonStandard custom control class.
This works, but I don't know if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good question. I would try to define an attached brush property and use `{TemplateBinding (myNamespace:PropertyClass.BrushPropertyName)}`, but I'm not sure if it would work. What would work is to use `VisualTreeHelper` to find the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` in the template of the button (once it loads), find the group and state by names, get the Storyboard/Animation/KeyFrame by index (since you can't read what the `Storyboard` targets) and set the `Value`. That's a bit hacky but who knows - maybe it would be faster than parsing yet another control template... Another option might be to try fiddling with [`CustomVisualStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.customvisualstatemanager.aspx).